# generate ssrs report on demand & send in email

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssis

Hi I am using SSRS for reporting.
And in asp.net application on the web page providing user to select parameters like for which region & for how many client they want report.

Now as we are having millions of records, we can not make user to sit for hours until report get generated.

So for that i want to call SSRS report to be generated & email to user when user save selection and give user message that report will be sent to you via email..

So my query is 
should i use stored procedure to call SSRS report?

or

should i call SSIS package which will in turn call SSRS report and send report in email?

Comment: You are using the SSIS package to handle the processing and the SSRS report to display a summary of some kind, right?

Comment: I have created report in ssrs. Now need to generate report in pdf or any other format when user put request from asp.net website form.so i want to start report generation at that time and save that report in some directory and then send it in email.

Comment: You can also look up data driven report subscriptions. Insert a one time report subscription record to run immediately and set the users email via the subscription.

Comment: With the data driven subscription i can start subscription and then allow user to leave web page, correct?

Comment: @lrb your suggestion worked. Now i want to know as this one time subscriptions will create jobs whenever users ask for reports in sql, should i delete those subscriptions after sometime?

Comment: No do not delete it. because it has been triggered and will not be triggered again. However, if you would like to add reoccurring subscriptions to your reports then you should look into subscription services of ssrs.

Comment: Thanks @lrb :) , i wanted specifically one time subscription.
Actually i asked for deletion as so many subscription will be created as there will be frequent request for report & in report database it will have so many entries & so many jobs in sql.

Answer (score 0):

@GMD The Subscription can be created with the users choice like daily/Weekly/Monday/Tuesday... also we could configure the time to run and deliver the report too.

These subscription can be created on Reporting Manager where we usually deploy SSRS reports and run the reports to view output.

Once the subscription was created say for Eg., Subscription created to run every Tuesday @ 6.00 PM. The report will ran every week on the specific time and the out put will be delivered to the persons whose mailID's were supplied during creating Subscription.